# Could not find Console App (.NET Core) template in Visual Studio on Creating a New Project

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework docs, it is mentioned to select **Console App (.NET Core)** with the C# tag on creating a new project(at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=visual-studio#:%7E:text=Select%20Console%20App%20(.NET%20Core)%20with%20the%20C%23%20tag%20and%20click%20Next)).

However, I was not able to find such a template in Visual Studio 2022.
[image]

Which template should I choose to proceed with?

Also, If I were to work with Entity Framework 6 (rather than EF Core), then which template should I choose?

Comment: See the button down there? Press it to install the missing features.

Comment: Use the Console App template

Comment: .NET Core is the default now. .NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core. v4.8.x is the last version of .NET Framework so there is no longer any need for differentiation in the naming. If it doesn't specify that it's targeting .NET Framework, it's targeting .NET Core.

Comment: "Console App" = console app for **.NET Core** - "Console App (.NET Framework)" = console app for the legacy/Windows-only **.NET** framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2020, .NET Core merged with .NET Framework into just .NET. Therefore, you wouldn't see the first one in template list. Use regular "Console App" template, as it uses .NET. You can downgrade back to .NET Core in project properties at any time.

P.S. You can install Entity Framework 6 in NuGet PM, alongside EF Core. Note that EF6 is outdated, so EF Core is recomended.

Answer (score 0):

You can use console application template. Each .NET core application is a console application.

You can refer [this](https://learnwithmainul.com/2016/02/09/basic-console-application-using-entity-framework/) for EF 6 related questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create "Console App" as a project and use the core features,EF6 and it is different from ConsoleApp(.net core)
does not have

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).